# Hovering over the element on the right side trigger css change of element to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build custom rating module to support my needs. I have a row of 5 different criterias - if you hoover over the one being on 2nd column - both the 2nd column star nad 1st column star should change it's color. Same for 5th - 5th, 4th, 3rd, 2nd and 1st column star should change it's color.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Here is the code:

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-20 col-md-20 ratingi">
<p> <small> Oceń: </small></p>
<p> <strong> Smak posiłku: </strong> </p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-20 col-md-20 ratingi">
<p><small> niejadalne </small> </p>
<h3> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-20 col-md-20 ratingi">
<p><small> niesmaczne </small> </p>
<h3> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-20 col-md-20 ratingi">
<p> <small>takie sobie </small> </p>
<h3> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-20 col-md-20 ratingi">
<p> <small>smaczne </small> </p>
<h3> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-20 col-md-20 ratingi">
<p> <small>palce lizać</small> </p>
<h3> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-20 col-md-20 ratingi">
<p> <small>Nie chcę oceniać</small> </p>
<p> <input type="checkbox" name="brakoceny" value="skip"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.col-xs-20,
.col-sm-20,
.col-md-20,
.col-lg-20 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.col-xs-20 {
     width: 14.25%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-sm-20 {
         width: 14.25%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-20 {
         width: 14.25%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-20 {
        width: 14.25%;
        float: left;
    }
}

.ratingi i {
color: #D1D1D1; 
}

.ratingi i:hover {
color: #5cb85c; 
cursor:pointer;
}
```

and a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fb897pLm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it with jQuery. I have created a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/YwjOpe). It is possible to even have hover effect after clicking the element.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li data-status="0">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li data-status="0">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li data-status="0">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li data-status="0">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li data-status="0">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o" data-status="0"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
 decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 3px;
 font-size: 2.5em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("ul li").mouseenter(function () {
    var $Sel = $(this).closest("ul");

    // removing existing fa-star classes on all <li> tags
    $Sel.children("li").each(function () {
        $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
    });

    // applying new condition
    for (i = 0; i <= $(this).index() ; i++) {
        $Sel.find("li").eq(i).find("i")
            .removeClass("fa-star-o")
            .addClass("fa-star");
    }
 });


 $("ul li").mouseleave(function () {
    var $Sel = $(this).closest("ul");
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

        if (($Sel.find("li").eq(i).attr("data-status") * 1) == 0) {
            $Sel.find("li").eq(i).find("i")
            .addClass("fa-star-o")
            .removeClass("fa-star");
        } else {
            $Sel.find("li").eq(i).find("i")
            .removeClass("fa-star-o")
            .addClass("fa-star");
        }

    }
  });


 $(document).on("click", "ul li", function (event) {

    var $Sel = $(this).closest("ul");

    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (i <= $(this).index()) {
            $Sel.find("li").eq(i)
            .attr("data-status", 1)
            .children("i")
                .removeClass("fa-star-o")
                .addClass("fa-star");
        } else {
            $Sel.find("li").eq(i)
            .attr("data-status", 0)
            .children("i")
                .addClass("fa-star-o")
                .removeClass("fa-star");
        }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: works like intended, much appreciated, thanks! I'm going to work a bit more on it so I can add few rows of those and style it same way as in the first time.

Comment: glad it helped. of course, you can achieve desired styles by simply adding/removing CSS classes on the element.

Comment: one more question - sorry if trival - I'm still learning. When I put the code you have prepared inside the bootstrap column layout - it does seem to break the .js working. It is because the ul class element is overiding the column class?

Comment: if you do not change ul>li structure, the code should work. If you want, update the CODEPEN example with your new HTML markups so that we can pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I've got it. I've included bootstrap column layout inside the ui element. Thanks again!

Comment: or not :) When I don't select any star and leave outside hover area - it selects all stars as default. How to switch it to none? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVjzoV

Comment: it is because you put "data-status" on <i> element and not <li> element. I just moved the data variable to <li> and it is working like a charm. Check out in here http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/eJjPoL

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to do it is by making an array where u store your star's class.

-> add new class to your 5 icons for eg s1,s2..s5 and store these class names in a array
then u can use js to check which icon user is Hovering and color all the elements to the left using the array u made.

i would suggest you u use jquery to make it even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using radio buttons and HTML and CSS only.

HTML:

```
<div class="rating">

<input type="radio" id="stars5" name="rating" value="5">
<label for="stars5">5 stars</label>

<input type="radio" id="stars4" name="rating" value="4">
<label for="stars4">4 stars</label>

<input type="radio" id="stars3" name="rating" value="3">
<label for="stars3">3 stars</label>

<input type="radio" id="stars2" name="rating" value="2">
<label for="stars2">2 stars</label>

<input type="radio" id="stars1" name="rating" value="1">
<label for="stars1">1 star</label>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rating {
    float:left;
}

.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float: right;
    width: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #ccc;
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★';
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: orange;
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: orange;
}
```

http://codepen.io/williamjamesclark/pen/xZJajX